# Finding Probability of a state being reached from a specific state

Tags: probability-theory

Lets say we can go from a states **A**, **B**, and **C** to a state **D**(We might also go to some other states) or can stay at the same state i.e **A**, **B** or **C**.
And the probability to go from **A** to **D** in one step is  **P<sub>ad</sub>** and to stay at sate **A** is **P<sub>aa</sub>**. 
Similarly for state **B** the probabilities are **P<sub>bd</sub>** and **P<sub>bb</sub>** and for state **C** we have **P<sub>cd</sub>** and **P<sub>cc</sub>**.
How do we find the probability of reaching **D**, from **A**, **B**, **C** respectively.

Comment: You should precise in how many steps you want to reach $D$. In any case, that is a Markov Chain : you should investigate this theory.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you cannot move from state A to state B or C and vice versa. From A you can only either (i) stay at A, or (ii) move to D, or (iii) move to some other state E different from A, B, C from which it is impossible to get to D.

If this assumption is correct then the probabilities relating to A, B, C are independent so there are 3 identical independent problems here. Each will have the same solution with the probabilities replaced for the appropriate starting state.

Consider only outcomes for A. At the end of each move if we reach D or E the game ends. If we stay at A we start the game over again with the probabilities of reaching D or E being exactly the same as before. So we only have to compare the probabilities of reaching D and E in one move.

The conditional probability of reaching D given that we started from A is $$p(D|A)=\frac{P_{ad}}{P_{ad}+P_{ae}}=\frac{P_{ad}}{1-P_{aa}}$$ (*Check :* If the option of moving to E is removed then $P_{ae}=0$. Every game ends on D eventually so $p(D|A)=1$.)

Similar expressions can be written for $p(D|B)$ and $p(D|C)$.

Comment: what will be the sum of p(D|A) + p(D|B) + p(D|C)?

Comment: You can easily work that out for yourself but it will not be meaningful because - as your question is written - these 3 probabilities are independent. If you want to know the probability of reaching D having started at A or B or C then you need to multiply each term by the probability of starting from that state.

Comment: My main question is If I am at D and want to know the probability that I have arrived here from A, B or C. Shouldn't the sum of answers for these three be 1.Maybe I am asking p((A|D)|D) if that makes sense, I am not sure. Could you suggest some readings to get better at such questions.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer that question. We need to know more about how D can be reached from states other than A or B or C. Sorry I don't know what to read. Try searching Google or search this site for "probability resources".

Comment: We can reach D only from A, B, and C.I meant to ask that I'll find this stuff under conditional probability or is there something else involved.

Comment: Yes this topic is "conditional probability." Related terms are "prior probability" and "posterior probability."

Comment: As I said above, if you want to know the probability of having started from A, given that you have reached D, then you need to know the probabilities of starting from A, B, C : $$p(A|D)=p(A)p(D|A)$$